# Linux xfce4 with login user command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfce, session

I have a Linux Ubuntu 20.04 computer running Xubuntu. I am in the process of writing a c ++ program that consists of a completely new login screen. This login screen also works and I can check whether the password I entered is correct. But now I somehow need a way to actually log the user into the Linux system. Currently the command `sudo xfce4-session` is simply executed after a successful data entry. Everything works great, but unfortunately the Xfce4 desktop always starts as root. But I don't want that. How can I somehow enter the user who is logged in when starting the desktop with the command `sudo xfce4-session` or how can I otherwise start a session so that another nurse is automatically logged in when the command is executed. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Do you check the password yourself, or is there a system call to do this for you?

Comment: I check the password on my own on a database